# copy app database from second app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, io, copy

I have my android app (with source codes, but I am not very experienced android programmer) and I need second small app, which will be able to backup (simply copy) whole database file from first app to folder on device. I think something like "content provider" must be implemented in the first app to allow second app to copy its database (to grant permissions). Could you point me please how to do it (implement content provider) and how to make second app?

It should be just icon and when I click on this icon it will copy database and shows toast "Database backed up.". That's it.
P.S. tutorial is highly appreciated if possible.

Comment: follow this tutorial, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html and https://www.academia.edu/4446368/Android_SQLite_Database_and_Content_Provider_Tutorial

Comment: Do you need 2 applications conformly means why can't you provide a widget of first application and when it is clicked copy the databse .

Comment: have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718891/can-i-access-database-of-one-application-from-another-application-android and http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/content-provider-in-android.html#.WCq19NV961s

Comment: @Narender Reddy because I need to be sure, if the first app collapses, I need to have second app as "emergency option to backup data".

Comment: copy that data into internal storage and hide that folder.so you can only means your's applications only  access it