# Can I share android one application database with same application which is installed in other phone in case of same WiFi network?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I have two android devices and my application is installed on both device .those devices are in same WiFi network so can I share one application database with other application which is installed in other device ?

Comment: follow below link which help you to access your application database by using content providers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718891/accessing-the-database-of-one-application-from-another-application

Comment: @ChiragArora thank you . i want to access the db of 1 app to other app which is installed in other android device

Comment: You cannot.You need to she db file from one device to another device .Like that only you can able to share the db